# Shared variable content lost through drill down

Tags: crystal-reports

Using the latest version of crystal report.

In my page header I have a **subreport** that fetches some dates into a shared date variable.

In one of my grouping I have a Hidden section, therefore only available through drill down, which also runs a subreport recalling the same shared date variable from the initial subreport. If I don't hide that grouping the information passed through the shared variable is fine. But if I hide the grouping and drill down on that section then the content gets lost.

Has anyone ever had that same issue?

Comment: I have it now. Did you figure out what happened?

Answer (score 0):

If its not in the drill down you can't use it. So what I do to use it is make the field super tiny and make the font white so it doesn't appear on the report, but still leave it in a drilled down section.